# Finding Top Left and Bottom Right Points (C++)

Tags: c++, polygon

I'm looking for some help with a project I'm working on.

What I'm doing is a polygon approximation algorithm. I've got all of the points of my boundary, but in order to start the algorithm, I need to find the top left and bottom right points from the set of points. All of the points are stored in a structure array that has the x and y coordinates of each point. Any ideas on an easy way to loop through the array of points?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. If you need more information, just ask and I'll provide all I can.

Comment: Yes, I've got idea how " loop through the array of point" - use `for` statement or `while`

Comment: Obviously there is going to be some kind of loop. I need to figure out how to determine the top left and bottom right points though. If it were bottom left and top right, it would just be the smallest x+y and the biggest x+y, but that's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: What is the definition of the top left point? Is it the point with the highest y and lowest x? What happens when you have competing criteria, eg two points, one has highest y, but not lowest x, the other has lowest x but not highest y. How do you pick the winner.

Comment: To make it clear; do you need the corners of your bounding rectangle? Or a point from the polygon set?

Comment: Biggest x+y is hardly "top right". If you stretch your polygon along one axis, "top" and "right" stay the same, but your "top right" changes. It is not clear why "top right" would be important for polygon approximation. Anyway, if that's what you want, consider that flipping the sign of the x coordinate reverses "left" and "right".

Comment: I'm only doing them because that's what my professor told us to do. The object that I will be performing the algorithm on will all be in the first quadrant, so all of the values are positive. I just need the point from the array I built.

Comment: Using Pythagoras Theorem, top right is sqrt(x^2 + y^2), as it measures the distance from (0,0)  to (x,y). Not even this approach works perfectly. If you have a big value coordinate and another is very low value, this could be the more distant point to (0,0) and not be the top right point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your comment that bottom left is `min(x+y)` and top right is `max(x+y)`

Top left: `min(x+max(y)-y)`

Bottom right: `max(max(x)-x+y)`

Where the inner `max` is a constant.

Though this may not always give a result that agrees with your eyes.

Alternative metrics can be constructed based on the distance from the corners of the bounding box of your object, or the square of the distance, etc.

Another technique is to translate the polygon around the origin and then top left is the point furthest from the origin but in the top left quadrant... That gives a whole heap of choices as to where to put `(0,0)` could be average of all, could be weighted average based on some rule, etc. lot of variability in how you pick that, each may give results that differ for a very small number if polygons from what the eye would pick.

Finally you could always train a neural network to pick the answer.... That might result in something that is (insert confidence limits from training)% likely to give an answer you agree with... But you and I may disagree

Comment: If `max(y)` is a constant, you might as well subtract it from all numbers in the set.

Comment: I just got an email from my professor that we can use the bottom left and top right for the assignment. So I'll go ahead and use that. Thanks for the help everyone. I'll likely be asking more questions related to this project over the next few days on here. Really impressed with the response time.

Answer (score 0):

Top left: min(x+max(y)-y)

Bottom right: min(max(x)-x+y)

Where the inner max is a constant.

Answer (score 0):

For the corners I used 2 indicator variables left and up which can have the values {-1,1}.

For upper corners (i.e. top-Left and top-Right) up := 1,
if its a lower corner (i.e. bottom-left and bottom-right) up:= -1 .

Analogously for the left variable:
left:= 1 for top-left and bottom-left
left := -1 for top-right and bottom right

Then the corner can be found by maximizing the term

left * point.x + up * point.y

over all Coordinates.