# how to find extreme point of the contour opencv c++

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, contour

I have this image:

[image]

How do i can implement the extreme point finder code in OpenCv c++ like in the picture?

Anyone have any idea please??

```
# determine the most extreme points along the contour

leftmost = tuple(cnt [cnt[:,:,0].argmin()][0]);
rightmost = tuple(cnt [cnt[:,:,0].argmax()][0]);
topmost = tuple(cnt [cnt[:,:,1].argmin()][0]);
bottommost = tuple(cnt [cnt[:,:,1].argmax()][0]);
```

Comment: I think you can find answer at this post [Find extreme points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13507550/finding-top-left-and-bottom-right-points-c)

Comment: You can just use [std::minmax_element](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/minmax_element/) with a lambda function. One time the lambda function should compare x and the other time compares y. Or [std::minmax](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/minmax/) if you only need the points

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you already have the contour and it is as a vector of points, you can use the [std::minmax_element](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/minmax_element/) function for the same end. It supports a comparison method that can be whatever you want if it follows the signature. So a simple code similar to what you do would be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

// this is not necessary, just for testing (OpenCV Points should be used instead)
struct Point
{
    int x;
    int y;


    Point():
    x(0), y(0){}
    Point(int xVal, int yVal):
    x(xVal), y(yVal){}
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Point> cnt = {
        {1,2},{4,5},{1,6}, {7,8}, {9,3}, {2,6}
    };

    // compare x axis
    auto val = std::minmax_element(cnt.begin(), cnt.end(), [](Point const& a, Point const& b){
        return a.x < b.x;
    });

    std::cout << " leftMost [ " << val.first->x << ", " << val.first->y << " ]" << std::endl;
    std::cout << " RightMost [ " << val.second->x << ", " << val.second->y << " ]" << std::endl;

    // compare y axis
    val = std::minmax_element(cnt.begin(), cnt.end(), [](Point const& a, Point const& b){
        return a.y < b.y;
    });

    std::cout << " TopMost [ " << val.first->x << ", " << val.first->y << " ]" << std::endl;
    std::cout << " BottomMost [ " << val.second->x << ", " << val.second->y << " ]" << std::endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Here is a [link](https://onlinegdb.com/ByIPxejkz) to run it.

In this example the Point struct is just to simulate OpenCV one, but it will work exactly the same. The I create a test vector, run `minmax_element` comparing only the `x` axis and print the results. I do the same with the `y` axis.

This function returns a pair of iterators to such objects, if you need them to be returned make sure to copy them :)

Comment: thank you for your reply but what if my vector is:                                                                                        vector< vector<Point> > contours; to use in robotic manipulation i have to need this extreme point as pixel.

Comment: since i have to use the :::`findContours(temp, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_CCOMP, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);` function to find the same contour in real time. it shows fatel error

Comment: What error? edit your question (use the edit botton below it) and add an update to your question. You should do it to `contours[i]`. `contours` is a vector of vector of points, and the function work with a vector of points, and you need first to check if it has points, if not it will give error.

Comment: thank you very much!! my problem is :- when i use ` vector< vector<Point> > contours;` your program doesnot works. and when i use  `vector<Point> > contours`only my `findContours(temp, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_CCOMP, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);` does not works

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error (active) E0312 no suitable user-defined conversion from "std::vector<cv::Point, std::allocator<cv::Point>>" to "cv::Point" exists ql

Comment: That means that you passed `vector<Point>` where it needed just `Point`

Answer (score -2):

```
void thresh_callback(int, void* )
{
    Mat canny_output;
    vector<vector<Point> > contours;
    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;

    Canny( src_gray, canny_output, thresh, thresh*2, 3 );
    findContours( canny_output, contours, hierarchy, RETR_TREE, CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0) );

    Mat drawing = Mat::zeros( canny_output.size(), CV_8UC3 );

    for( size_t i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++ )
    {
        Scalar color = Scalar( rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0,255), rng.uniform(0,255) );
        drawContours( drawing, contours, (int)i, color, 2, 8, hierarchy, 0, Point() );
    }

    namedWindow( "Contours", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    imshow( "Contours", drawing );
}
```

to use this code how does above code works